# Knocking/clunking sound coming from back end on flat road

Tags: tires, noise, suspension, mitsubishi, knock

I drive a 2014 Mitsubishi RVR and for a couple of months now there has been a knocking noise coming from the back end of the vehicle. At first it was very faint and you could only hear it when the windows were up and silence in the car, but now the noise is EXTREMELY loud and even when you sit in the back seat as a passenger you can feel it knocking under your feet on both sides. The car doesn't shake, bounce or in any way feel bumpy as if it were a suspension issue and its not a noise that happens when going over bumps or uneven roads. It's a constant clunking when driving on smooth pavement and the noise speeds up/slows down as you do when driving. Any ideas what it might be???

Comment: Let's just start with some basics here... To avoid ending up in a break-fix goose chase. Have you checked the cargo area for anything banking around? Is there anything loose in the spare-tire well/under all the cargo covers back there? Get all that stuff out and look for loose items that might be bouncing around. Easy place to start, and free. Hopefully it's this basic.

Answer (score 1):

Visit a wheel alignment shop and ask them for an inspection. Usually, rubber bushings wear out causing metal to metal contact.

Could be strut mount, trailing arm bushing, link bar, upper or lower control arm bushing, could be anything. Not even an experienced mechanic can know without looking umder there.

Answer (score 0):

This could literally be anything. Although your description does not give us much detail, I am going to take a guess here with a couple things it could be.

1. If this is 4-wheel drive or all-wheel drive, Mitsubishi calls it All Wheel Control, then it could be the driveshaft has come loose, is damaged or has something caught on it.
2. If this is front wheel drive only, then it could be that an exhaust
   pipe is touching the floorboard. This can happen when exhaust
   hangers break or get bent from hitting road debris, etc. For that matter, it could even be a tree branch stuck under the car.
3. Lastly, it could be some type of suspension has come loose. The
   suspension still moves on flat level roads.

You will need to, or have someone else, inspect under the vehicle to see what is happening.